# Maven: generate MANIFEST in custom location

Tags: maven, manifest.mf, maven-jar-plugin

I am trying to retrieve the implementation title and version for a maven jar module. If I use `Myclass.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` on the built jar, it works, but the same does not work in a debugging environment where the jar is not built, but classes are available.

I am aware of using the Maven JAR plugin to generate the MANIFEST for a maven jar module. So one approach I am considering is to somehow create a copy of the MANIFEST in the generated sources output folder, which I include in my debug classpath. To achieve this:

1. Is it possible to generate the MANIFEST file in a custom location? If so, what is the plugin and execution configuration necessary?
2. If not, in which location is the file generated, so I may copy it my custom location using the maven-resources-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The Manifest file is created dynamically when the archive is assembled. There is no default way to do this.
The easiest I would come up with is to put a `MANIFEST.MF` in a resource directory, let Maven filter it and add the directory with a profile. This would mimic the way Maven Archiver creates your `MANIFEST.MF`. The hard way would be to create a custom plugin around Maven Archiver and pass the very same config as to the JAR plugin and enable it with a profile again.